# How to get all tweets sent by someone with tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get all tweets sent by someone with tweepy ,take realDonaldTrump as example.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key="xxx"
consumer_secret="xxx"
access_token="xxx"
access_token_secret="xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump",count=200)
for info in tweets:
    print(info.text)
```

The output info are as following.
Two problems remain here.
1.How to get all tweets sent by DonaldTrump?
ALL of them ,not only 200.

2.How to get the full text of every tweet?
The full text for the second tweet is as following :
Marshawn Lynch of the NFL’s Oakland Raiders stands for the Mexican Anthem and sits down to boos for our National Anthem. Great disrespect! Next time NFL should suspend him for remainder of season. Attendance and ratings way down.

But the codes get part of the tweet as result.
Marshawn Lynch of the NFL’s Oakland Raiders stands for the Mexican Anthem and sits down to boos for our National An....
[image: tweets send by DonaldTrump]

Comment: It is worth checking what limitations twitter imposes on it's API. There is a good chance a lot of these issues are not possible to work around, and are limitations twitter are using to reduce other websites over-consuming their resources. Things like 200 items per request sound normal for an API limitation. (EDIT: Can confirm for the 200 limitation, this IS the limitation from twitter itself. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline)

Comment: To get the full text of a longer Tweet, use the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter and check the `full_text` field on the response.

It is not possible to get all the Tweets for a specific account that has been around for a number of years via the API. Each timeline request will by default return 200 characters. You can use API Cursoring (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/cursoring) to retrieve additional pages of results, but the timeline API tops out at 3200 Tweets. If you wanted more than that, you'd need to use Twitter's enterprise full archive search product (commercial).